# CommonErrorHandler not called with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: authentication, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to intercept Kafka authentication exceptions using a ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean. At the moment I configure a CommonErrorHandler instance on my ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory bean. The issue is that when authentication errors happen, the CommonErrorHandler is never called. My CommonErrorHandler simply logs the exception provided via handleOne and handleOtherException callbacks. Below is the code I am using:

```
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            final ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory,
            final ApplicationProperties appProperties) {

        final var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, byte[]>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        final var containerProperties = factory.getContainerProperties();
        containerProperties.setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);

        var errorHandler = new CommonErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public boolean seeksAfterHandling() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void handleOtherException(final Exception thrownException, final Consumer<?, ?> consumer, final MessageListenerContainer container, final boolean batchListener) {
                log.error("************************* Kafka error handleOtherException", thrownException);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean handleOne(final Exception thrownException, final ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, final Consumer<?, ?> consumer, final MessageListenerContainer container) {
                log.error("************************* Kafka error handleOne", thrownException);
                return true;
            }
        };
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        return factory;
    }
```

Also note that I manually create the MessageListener instances to dynamically assign a partition and topic like below:

```
final var partitionOffset = new TopicPartitionOffset(eventStream.getTopic(), eventStream.getPartition());
kafkaListenerContainer = kafkaContainerFactory.createContainer(partitionOffset);
kafkaMessageListener = new KafkaMessageListener();
kafkaListenerContainer.setupMessageListener(kafkaMessageListener);
kafkaListenerContainer.start();
```

Any help to make this working would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.